# How to show a line moving from top to bottom like in a scanning process?

Tags: android

I already spent multiple hours researching any possible solutions for this issue but I haven't had any success so far except for one question on this site ([How to show a moving line to show scanning in progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663449/how-to-show-a-moving-line-to-show-scanning-in-progress)). At first I thought I got the right answer right here, the only problem is the code doesn't seem to work (another user already stated that in the comments of the answer marked as solution). Does someone have any advice or a different approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use animations for this, in the following example this is a scanline from left to right

In the `activity.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
        <FrameLayout
             android:id="@+id/scanLine"
             android:layout_width="4dip"
             android:visibility="gone"
             tools:visibility="visible"
             android:background="#FFFFC000" />
....
```

In `yellow_line.glow.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#0fff"
                android:centerColor="@color/ioxp_yellow"
                android:endColor="#0fff"
                android:gradientRadius="1"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In `scanAnimation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:duration="2000" />
    <translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="99%p"
        android:duration="3000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse" />
</set>
```

And in `Activity.java`:

```
scanLine.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scanAnimation));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:You will use the AsyncTask class for displaying line or your scanning progress. Sample code is as follow:

```
public class LoadSome extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    ProgressDialog dialog;

  @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialog.setMax(100);
    dialog.show();
} 

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String colleted=null;

         for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
         {
             publishProgress(5);
             try {
                Thread.sleep(88);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
         dialog.dismiss();

          try
          {
            fis=openFileInput(FILENAME);
            byte[] byteArray=new byte[fis.available()];
            while (fis.read(byteArray)!=-1) {
                colleted=new String(byteArray);

            }
            //Toast.makeText(this, "load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //break;
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
            // TODO: handle exception
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
          finally
          {
            try 
            {
                fis.close();
                return colleted;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

          }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog.incrementProgressBy(values[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        t1.setText(result);
    }
}
```